# What are the products of these 3 reactants? Acetic Acid + K2CrO4(aq) + Ba(NO3)2(aq)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, bond

Acetic Acid + K2CrO4(aq) + Ba(NO3)2 (aq) —> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is

$$\ce{K2CrO4 + Ba(NO3)2 -> BaCrO4 + 2 KNO3}$$

The acetic acid does not intervene. $\ce{BaCrO4}$ is insoluble in the solution and make a pale yellow precipitate, that can be filtrated.

Comment: What’s the rationale behind acetic acid not having any effect on the reaction?

Comment: Acetic acid acid is probably here to be sure that the solution contains no carbonate ions from tap water. Carbonate ions may also reacts with Baryum nitrate, producing some Baryum carbonate which is also insoluble in water. Acetic acid reacts with carbonates which are transformed into $CO_2$ and acetate ions, and acetate ions are not perturbing the reaction.

Comment: While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/).